# sugarCRM how to populate a dropdown

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm using SugarCRM v6.5, I'm terribly newbie.
In the Leads, I wanted to add a field in the address type to indicate the type of address (ie office, home, ...). So in the studio I created this field "type_address" as an simple dropdown (don't know the term in english, in french it's "liste à choix simple") and I indicated the options to use to populate it. So far, it's ok, if I display it on a form, it populates correctly. But I 'd like to add it in the address field, so I opened include\SugarFields\Fields\Address\fr_FR.EditView.tpl and added a line like this :

```
<tr style="background-color: yellowgreen;">
<td valign="top" width='25%' scope='row' ><label for="{{$typeaddr}}">{sugar_translate label='LBL_{{$key}}_ADRESS_TYPE' module='{{$module}}'}:</label>
{if $fields.{{$typeaddr}}.required || {{if $typeaddr|lower|in_array:$displayParams.required}}true{{else}}false{{/if}}}
<span class="required">{$APP.LBL_REQUIRED_SYMBOL}</span>
{/if}
</td>
<td>
<select name="{{$typeaddr}}" id="{{$typeaddr}}" title=''  >
   {html_options options=$fields.{{$typeaddr}}.options }
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

and in the top of template I put :

```
{{assign var="typeaddr" value=$displayParams.key|cat:'_adress_type_c'}}
```

The line displays, the label is ok, but the dropdown does not populate.
I tried to indicate the options list in 
\custom\Extension\modules\Leads\Ext\Vardefs\sugarfields_primary_adress_type_c.php
like this :

```
$dictionary['Lead']['fields']['primary_adress_type_c']['type'] = 'base';
$dictionary['Lead']['fields']['primary_adress_type_c']['options'] = 'list_name_as_created_in_studio';
```

I also tried to put it in \custom\modules\Leads\metadata\editviewdefs.php

```
0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'primary_adress_type_c',
        'studio' => 'visible',
        'label' => 'LBL_PRIMARY_ADRESS_TYPE',
        'type' => 'base',
        'options' => list_name_as_created_in_studio',
      ),
```

I tried with both enum and base. The trick is, even if I put 'enum' and an array of options, it does not populate.

I don't see where I could interfere to make it work, I surely forgot to do something.

Any help is welcome, even a link to the manual (I read it and didn't find anything to help, but I could miss something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file `include\SugarFields\Fields\Address\fr_FR.EditView.tpl`, replace:

```
<select name="{{$typeaddr}}" id="{{$typeaddr}}" title=''  >
   {html_options options=$fields.{{$typeaddr}}.options }
</select>
```

with:

```
{html_options name=primary_adress_type_c options=$primary_adress_type_c_options selected=$fields.primary_adress_type_c.value}
```

Create a new file `custom/modules/Leads/views/view.edit.php` with contents

```
<?php
require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.edit.php');
class LeadsViewEdit extends ViewEdit{

    public function LeadsViewEdit(){
        parent::ViewEdit();
    }

  public function preDisplay() {
    parent::preDisplay();
    $this->ss->assign('primary_adress_type_c_options', $GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['list_name_as_created_in_studio']);
  }

    public function display(){
        parent::display();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you air4x, I could have searched a long long time before I find this... As I have 2 addresses (primery and alternative), I did it like that : `{html_options name={{$typeaddr}} options=$adress_type_c_options selected=$fields.{{$typeaddr}}.value}` and in the new file : `$this->ss->assign('adress_type_c_options', $GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['list_name_as_created_in_studio']);`
Thanks again !